WPF - How to use a font that is in another project
I need some help using a font that it's in another project where all my default styles are stored.
In Project A (GUILibrary) I have a resource dictionary named DefaultStyles.xaml with my desired Font Family and many other template styles.
<FontFamily x:Key="CavPlaywrite">Fonts/PlaywriteESDeco-Regular.ttf#Playwrite ES Deco</FontFamily>

In Project B, I reference Project A and I merge the dictionary in App.xaml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/GUILibrary;component/Templates/DefaultStyles.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/GUILibrary;component/Templates/DataTemplates.xaml"/>

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

Everything works well except for the font. All my styles can be used in Project B but the my desired font  is not applied. I get no error message.
(A very similar question was made 10 years ago, unfortunately no answer was given)
Thank very much for your help :)
